# How to efficiently share functions between classes without violating the Liskov Substitution Principle

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

I have a codebase that was originally created with a number of different options that allow you to get the code to perform the same process in a slightly different way, like this:

```
public class MainFunction {
  public void main(String option){
     if (option.equals("vanilla mode")){
        this.firstFunction();
     }else{
        this.differentVersionOfFirstFunction();
     }
     this.secondFunction();
  }

  public void firstFunction(){
    //First functions code
  }

  public void secondFunction(){
     //Second functions code
  }

  public void differentVersionOfFirstFunction(){
     // different code from First functions code that produces the same type of end result using a slightly different method
  }
}
```

This has gotten gradually more and more complex as various different options are added and the code becomes increasingly convoluted.

To resolve this I had originally planned to create a Parent object, that could then have children with subtlety different variations on their Parents methods when needed. The problem is that I understand that this would violate the Liskov Substitution Principle and indeed I may have children that should be sharing the same method that may not be present in their parent.

So I am left with having the different methods in the same class object, doing the same job in slightly different ways.

```
public class MainFunction {
  public void main1(){
    this.firstFunction();
    this.secondFunction();
  }

  public void main2(){
    this.differentVersionOfFirstFunction();
    this.secondFunction();
  }

  public void firstFunction(){
    //First functions code
  }

  public void secondFunction(){
    //Second functions code
  }

  public void differentVersionOfFirstFunction(){
    // different code from First functions code that produces the same type of end result using a slightly different method
  }
}
```

I suppose I could create a separate Utility class to hold all my various functions, but I was not sure if there was a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how your examples violate the *Liskov Substitution Principle*. However, what I see is that they probably violate *Open/Closed Principle*, meaning that every time you need to modify your program, you edit some `MainFunction.java` file and have a chance of affecting all possible scenarios of running the program. A better solution involves having a lot of decoupled components so that when you need to modify something, you modify only a tiny portion which is unlikely to affect all scenarios the program might encounter. This is what *Single Responsibility Principle* is about.

As mentioned in another answer, your scenario seems to be good fit to apply the strategy pattern. This might look as following:

1. Create interface `MainFunction` with `void main()` method, without any options.
2. Create an abstract strategy class such as `AbstractMainFunction` with a `public abstract void main()` member, without any options. This class will implement `MainFunction` interface.
3. Create separate implementations of the `AbstractMainFunction` as needed, e.g. `VanillaModeMainFunction` and `DifferentMainFunction`. You may find it useful to keep some shared code in the `AbstractMainFunction`.
4. Create a strategy-switcher class, e.g. `MainFunctionService`. It will have a method, `public void main(String option)` as in your first example, and probably will have a switch statement like that:

   ```
   MainFunction strategy = defaultFunction;
   switch(option) {
       case "vanilla":
            strategy = vanillaFunction;
            break;
       case "different":
            strategy = differentFunction;
            break;
   }
   strategy.main();
   ```

It looks like a lot of things to do but in the end you will see how this really simplifies maintenance and further development.

Comment: Doesn't this strategy-switcher class also violate the Open/Closed Principle?

Comment: @jaco0646, great question, and the answer is, probably, it depends :-). If there are way too many options and the format of options is complex then yes, it would probably be better to build the option-parsing function into the strategies themselves and apply the *chain of responsibility* pattern instead of the *strategy* pattern. However, if the logic is relatively simple, in my opinion, it would be perfectly fine for the program's entry point to have a switch statement, and it would adhere to Single Responsibility Principle -- only one reason to change, i.e. when a new option comes in.

Comment: Thanks, I have a working demo of this, now to transer over all my code!

Comment: I have implemented this, though I am not sure if I have it right, When I make a version of the Vanilla mode Main Function with say, a different number of required arguments for a key function, then a new function must be created in the child, and all the classes it inherits from, but this new function would be meaningless to other children that have no need of the extra argument?

Comment: If functions are so distinct that even their arguments differ, call the `main` method on strategies directly, e.g. `case "a": strategy1.main(a, b, c); break; case "b": streategy2.main(x, y, z);`. Consider also an idea of having a `Context` class that you would pass as a single argument to any strategy. The strategy will then itself extract the needed data from `Context`, or `Context` would have some common methods for arguments parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using the strategy pattern, injecting in your MainFunction the Strategy object that you need to use each time. Have a look [here](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-strategy)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the right sort of track, but I am still concerned that there may be some code duplication when I have two very similar implementations, I will give it a go and see how it works out.

Comment: If you are concerned about code duplication, checkout the *template method* pattern, may be it would help.